# Whats the meaning of AR2220 Router interface display?

Tags: router

In the Quidway `AR2220` Router, I display the interface:

```
[Huawei]display interface brief
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
^down: standby
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
GigabitEthernet0/0/0        down  down        0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/1        up    down        0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/2        down  down        0%     0%          0          0
NULL0                       up    up(s)       0%     0%          0          0
```

I have some questions about the display.

1) What's the difference between PHY and Protocol up and down?
2) What's the meaning of `spoofing`?
3) What's the meaning of `NULL0`? is it a interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PHY" refers to the [**physical** Layer-1 interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY_(chip)) – e.g. the signalling over an Ethernet cable – and basically shows whether the port is **connected.** Linux would refer to this as the "carrier", e.g. a physically-disconnected interface would show up as "NO-CARRIER".

"Protocol" refers to the **logical** interface within the router's OS and shows whether the port is **enabled for use.** (Also called 'administrative' up/down.)

"Null0" is a virtual interface that never sends or receives anything. It can be used, for example, as the destination of 'blackhole' routes which are meant to discard received traffic. (There's a [Huawei KB article](http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/knowledge/EKB0000209191) which I find very unclear, but I just assume it does the same as e.g. Cisco Null0.)

"Spoofing", as far as I could figure out from Huawei docs, is specific to virtual interfaces (such as Null0 or loopback) or dial-on-demand interfaces, and means that the logical interface is permanently "up" despite not belonging to any connected PHY. Again, this appears to be similar to [the same term in Cisco](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/5924).